# UnderscoreJS - Retrieve specific keys from an object within a object

Tags: underscore.js

I have the follow object that I'm trying to retrieve the `token` and `UserEmail` from `Details`

```
var obj = {
  "id": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "createdAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
  "Details":
    {
      "id": 1,
      "token": null,
      "deviceId": null,
      "code": 12345678,
      "verified": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
      "UserEmail": "joe@example.com"
    }
 }
```

I tried this but I'm getting a blank?

```
_.pick(_.pick(obj, 'Details'), 'code', 'UserEmail');
```

Comment: Details is an array, not an object.

Comment: oops I must've missed that. making the change now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_.pick(obj.Details, 'code', 'UserEmail')
```

Comment: I like this way: `_(obj.Details).pick('code', 'UserEamil')`

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `pick` will return you an object with a `Details` key, which you'll then have to access. Instead, do something like:

`_.pick(obj['Details'], 'code', 'UserEmail')`

Answer (score 0):

If you have strictly set Details key in your object then I see the following way:

```
function getUserDetails (obj) {
     return obj.Details;
}

_(getUserDetails(obj)).pick('userEmail', 'token');
```